# Random Generator - carrying over variables

Tags: java, android, variables, random

Would anyone please be able to help?
I am just starting out with some very basic android development.  I am developing an initial app to help my daughter learn her times tables.  Idea being (in its first version) randomly generate 2 numbers between 1 and 12.  Then click on a calculate button which will give the answer.
I have it so that it randomly generates the 2 numbers, however, when I click calculate, it does not calculate, simply shows 0.
I believe it is something to do with the value of the variables (digit1 & digit2) not being seen by the next method (calculate).  If I hard code 2 numbers into the calculate method, it works.  I just cannot the random generated numbers to calculate.
Any help would be most appreciated.
MainActivity.java:

```
package uk.co.myrayner.sophiestimestables;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int digit1;
    int digit2;
    int show_answer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void randomise_digits(View view) {
        Random rand1 = new Random();
        int digit1 = rand1.nextInt(12) + 1;
        displaydigit1(digit1);
        Random rand2 = new Random();
        int digit2 = rand2.nextInt(12) + 1;
        displaydigit2(digit2);
    }

    public void calculate(View view) {
        show_answer = (digit1 * digit2);
        displayanswer(show_answer);
    }

    private void displaydigit1(int number) {
        TextView digit1TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.digit1);
        digit1TextView.setText("" + number);
    }

    private void displaydigit2(int number) {
        TextView digit2TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.digit2);
        digit2TextView.setText("" + number);
    }

    private void displayanswer(int number) {
        TextView answerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_answer);
        answerTextView.setText("" + number);

    }
}
```

Comment: `calculate()` is not generating random numbers, `randomise_digits` is generating the numbers. Check if the click handlers are setup correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is remove the "int" before you define digit1 and digit2 so your code should look like this:

```
package uk.co.myrayner.sophiestimestables;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int digit1;
    int digit2;
    int show_answer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void randomise_digits(View view) {
        Random rand1 = new Random();
        digit1 = rand1.nextInt(12) + 1;
        displaydigit1(digit1);
        Random rand2 = new Random();
        digit2 = rand2.nextInt(12) + 1;
        displaydigit2(digit2);
    }

    public void calculate(View view) {
        show_answer = (digit1 * digit2);
        displayanswer(show_answer);
    }

    private void displaydigit1(int number) {
        TextView digit1TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.digit1);
        digit1TextView.setText("" + number);
    }

    private void displaydigit2(int number) {
        TextView digit2TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.digit2);
        digit2TextView.setText("" + number);
    }

    private void displayanswer(int number) {
        TextView answerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_answer);
        answerTextView.setText("" + number);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your implementation.

1) Inside your randomise_digits you are setting the values of digit1 and digit2, but those are **local variables**, not the instance variables declared outside of the method. So any changes to digit1 and digit2 inside randomise_digits() is not reflected on the digit1 and digit2 of your MainActivity object. That is why you are getting 0 because they are not actaully set to any value (Since you refer to the instance variables of digit1 and digit2 inside your calculate() method). The local digit1 and digit2 in your randomise_digits() method is now out of scope/does not exist anymore.

2) Change the name of your method to better reflect what they are doing. Your calculate() method should probably renamed to show(). You don't need to pass in View objects as parameters for all of your methods. You are not using them so why include them?

3) You do not need to create two random objects to calculate two random numbers. One will do just fine.

Your class should probably look something like this:

```
package uk.co.myrayner.sophiestimestables;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int digit1;
    int digit2;
    int show_answer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button calculateButton = findViewById(R.id.your_calculate_button_id);

        calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                randomise_digits();
                calculate();
            }

        });
    }

    public void randomise_digits() {
        Random rand1 = new Random();
        digit1 = rand1.nextInt(12) + 1;
        displaydigit1(digit1);
        digit2 = rand1.nextInt(12) + 1;
        displaydigit2(digit2);
    }

    public void calculate() {
        show_answer = (digit1 * digit2);
        displayanswer(show_answer);
    }

    private void displaydigit1(int number) {
        TextView digit1TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.digit1);
        digit1TextView.setText("" + number);
    }

    private void displaydigit2(int number) {
        TextView digit2TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.digit2);
        digit2TextView.setText("" + number);
    }

    private void displayanswer(int number) {
        TextView answerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_answer);
        answerTextView.setText("" + number);

    }
}
```

Make sure to remove any onclick events in your activity's layout xml if you decide to copy and paste the code above.

Comment: Thank you so much, have got it working by removing the int from within the randomise_digits method.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't  test your code in my machine. But I think it may be caused by that you haven't set value of your global variables 'digit1' and 'digit2'.
In your method 'randomise_digits', you just create new local variables  'digit1' and 'digit2'.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't test your code but apparently, you declared `digit1` and `digit2` as global variables but when you use it, you declared it again so now the code will generate the random number and assign to the local `digit1` and `digit2` and not the global and when you try to call `calculate()`, global `digit1` and `digit2` are still 0 (primitive integer is zero by default) so basically the result will be zero.

Just modify randromise_digits function to

```
public void randomise_digits(View view) {
    Random rand1 = new Random();
    digit1 = rand1.nextInt(12) + 1;
    displaydigit1(digit1);
    Random rand2 = new Random();
    digit2 = rand2.nextInt(12) + 1;
    displaydigit2(digit2);
}
```